# Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spacy

first post newbie etc. I am trying to do topic modelling and have downloaded spacy but when trying to use the en_core_web_lg i receive the following error message:

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

i have tried to use the anaconda powershell with this code:
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

but i get an error AttributeError: module 'click.utils' has no attribute '_expand_args'

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You probably need to download the large model first `
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg`.  The command you used in line 3 of your question only downloads the small model.